# Let $\theta(z) = \sum q^{n^2}$, is $\theta(-1/z)$ also a theta function?

Tags: special-functions, theta-functions

I am learning about theta functions.  Let $q = e^{2\pi i \,  z}$ and $\theta(z) = \sum q^{n^2}$.  How does it behave under $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ?  In general we have:

$$ \theta\left( - \frac{1}{4z} \right) = \sqrt{- 2\pi i \, z} \; \theta(z) $$

Unfortunately, the maps $z \mapsto z + 1$ and $z \mapsto - \frac{1}{4z}$ do not generate all of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ but only $\Gamma_0(4)$ which is:

$$ \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right): ad-bc=1 \text{ and } 4 \, \big| \,c  \right\} $$

What is happening then under the map $z \mapsto - \frac{1}{z}$?  My guess it is some other theta function, but which kind?

Comment: It's $\theta\left(-\frac{1}{4z}\right) = \sqrt{-2\mathrm{i}z} \; \theta(z)$ (without $\pi$). [Cf. DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7.E32); their $q=\exp(\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$, so replace their $z$ with $0$ and their $\tau$ with your $2z$.